# How can I get my Bootstrap navigation bar text to align in the center of my page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have tried as many different methods as I could think of, as well as looking online to troubleshoot. And I can't for the life of me get my navigation text to center. It seems to be floating to the left and I don't know how to stop it from doing so. What can I do to get it to sit in the center? I know how to do it without Boostrap but it seems that Boostrap has set some rules that make it stick to the left and I don't know how to counteract that.

```css
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #00560C;
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar li {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Prescriptions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you want to make your navbar center or inner text alone ?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 @cfnerd

Comment: I would like to make the text align in the center. The navbar fills up the whole width of the page and I wanted the page links to display in the middle of this. Currently it is like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/qusg6fk72tvjf34/TRGGPhp.png?dl=0 @MohideenibnMohammed but I don't want the links to align to the left, I want them to align to the center but I can't seem to get it to do so...

Comment: Couldn't find a solution? @MohideenibnMohammed

Comment: do u have sample ? because 2 types of center are there. text center block center. text center will center text alone, block center will bring block center of the page